# Pattern matching list of lists containing only numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I'm trying to define a pattern that will match lists of lists, where the inner lists contains only numbers (I want the sum of each list). Like this

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

But not like this

```
{1, {1, 3},{{3}}}
```

Why this is not working?

```
Clear[foo];
foo[x : {v___List}] := Plus @@@ x /; VectorQ[v, NumberQ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: your condition `VectorQ[v, NumberQ]` for `v=Sequence[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]` becomes `VectorQ[{1, 2}, {3, 4}, NumberQ]` thus you get the error message `VectorQ::argt: VectorQ called with **3** arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo[x : {___List?(VectorQ[#, NumberQ] &)}] := Plus @@@ x

foo[{{1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}}]
```

> {3, 9}

```
foo[{{1, 2}, {{3}}}]
```

> foo[{{1, 2}, {{3}}}]

Note: You need to use `NumericQ` in place of `NumberQ` if you want `foo[{{1, 2}, {2, 3, π}}]` to return `{3, 2 + 3 π}`.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use Total, with a condition to forbid it from totaling entries with a single term:

```
f[x_] := If[Length[x] > 1, Total[x], x]
```

For instance:

```
f /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}}
{3, 9}
f /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {{3}}}
{3, 9, {{3}}}
```